# Is it possible to increase a window's border area for resizing the window with the mouse?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

For a simple WPF window, is it possible to increase the area where the mouse can resize the window? For example:

[image: Trial]

The border is too thin. I tried the following workarounds but only the edge part of the window acts as an area for resizing:

1. Increasing `BorderThickness` of the window
2. Setting [`WS_THICKFRAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx#WS_THICKFRAME)

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: My tentative guess is that you'll likely have to implement your own custom resizing logic.

Comment: Same thoughts. [Commented that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43061833/7050782) on [Thiyagu Rajendran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6733080/thiyagu-rajendran)'s answer. I'll just add it as an answer once its done if there are no other possible methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set WindowStyle="None" and set borderbrush and borderthickness to achieve what you expect.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="100" WindowStyle="None" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" >
 Hello World
</Window>
```

Hope it works for you!

Or use Wpf custom window, Windows edge resize feature

[Wpf custom window, Windows edge resize feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157390/wpf-custom-window-windows-edge-resize-feature)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to increase the area that allows resizing of the whole window. Only the edge seems to allow resizing. See my edited question for details. I think it's possible to use a custom border and just manually set its own mouseDown/mouseMove/mouseUp for the drag behavior. I'll check it out first.

Comment: ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" add it. You will get a grip to resize the window as you wish.

Comment: It will increase the area to resize the window.

Comment: Yes, but only the lower right part. The question asks for the whole border area.

"**CanResizeWithGrip**. This option has the same functionality as CanResize, but adds a "resize grip" to the lower right corner of the window.""

Comment: Then you may go for custom window edge resize grip. I have updated my answer with a link with a resolution. Check it.

Comment: Windows Edge resize feature actually worked. Thanks for this!